# Replacing span tag with anchor tag using replaceChild javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to replace the span with id='water' with an anchor when the button is clicked using replaceChild in js. fff() works fine, so does ff() until the last two rows where i think the problem is. (I cant figure out how replaceChild works).

```
function fff() {
        var ss = document.createElement('span');
        var text = document.createTextNode('https://www.google.com/');
        ss.appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById('water').appendChild(ss);
    }
    function ff() {
        var s = document.createElement('a');
        var t = document.createTextNode("https://www.google.com/");
        s.appendChild(t);
        s.href = "http://example.com";
        var item = document.getElementById('water');
        item.replaceChild(s, item);
    }

<body onload="fff()">
<span id="water"></span> <br><br>
<button onclick="ff()">Replace with anchor</button>
</body>
```

And I get this when I click the button http://prntscr.com/d0b95v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element.replaceChild is used to replace a child of Element by another element. Since you want to replace the span#water, you have to select its parent (which is `<body>`) and call replaceChild. You might change your last line of ff to this

```
var body = document.body;
body.replaceChild(s, item);
```

Comment: Or, for a more generic solution: `s.parentNode.replaceChild(...)`